# How to upload Image to Cloudinary - MERN Stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mern, cloudinary

I want to add some company details to mongo DB, and the details include a company logo. So I want to upload the picture to Cloudinary and then save the URL in Mongo DB with the other details.

But my code doesn't seem to work. When I fill the form and click on submit, the image gets uploaded to Cloudinary but it does not get saved in the Database.

To store the image

```
const [ companyLogo, setCompanyLogo] = useState("");
const [ companyLogoURL, setCompanyLogoURL] = useState("");
```

Function to execute on submit

```
const handleCompanySubmit = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    const data = new FormData()
    data.append("file", companyLogo)
    data.append("upload_preset", "Sprint")
    data.append("cloud_name", "sprint-ccp")
    fetch("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/sprint-ccp/image/upload",{
      method:"post",
      body:data
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      setCompanyLogoURL(data.url)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })

    //check for empty fields
    if (
      isEmpty(companyName) ||
      isEmpty(companyAddress) ||
      isEmpty(companyRegNumber) ||
      isEmpty(companyContactNumber)
    ) {
      setCompanyErrorMsg("Please Fill All The Fields");
    }else {
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('companyName', companyName);
      formData.append('companyAddress', companyAddress);
      formData.append('companyRegNumber', companyRegNumber);
      formData.append('companyContactNumber', companyContactNumber);
      formData.append('companyLogo', companyLogoURL);

      setCompanyLoading(true);

      addCompany(formData)
      .then((response) => {
        setCompanyLoading(false);
          setCompanySuccessMsg(response.data.successMsg)
          setCompanyData({
            companyName: "",
            companyAddress: "",
            companyRegNumber: "",
            companyContactNumber: ""
          });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setCompanyLoading(false);
        setCompanyErrorMsg(err.response.data.errorMsg)
      })
    }
  };

const handleCompanyLogo = (evt) => {
    setCompanyLogo(evt.target.files[0])
  };
```

frontend view

```
<form className="register-form" onSubmit={handleCompanySubmit} noValidate>

     <label className="text-secondary">Company Logo :</label>
     <input type="file"  className="form-control" onChange={handleCompanyLogo}/>

     //remaining input fields

     <button className="btn btn-info submitButton" >Submit</button>
                  
</form>
```

api for adding company

```
export const addCompany = async (data) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };
  
    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:5000/api/auth/clients/company",
      data,
      config
    );
  
    return response;
  };
```

controller in backend

```
exports.addNewCompany = async(req,res)=>{

  const { 
    companyName,
    companyAddress,
    companyRegNumber,
    companyContactNumber,
    companyLogo
  } = req.body;

  const company = await Company.findOne({ companyName });
    if (company) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        errorMsg: `${req.body.companyName} already exists`,
      });
    }

  try{
    const newCompany = new Company();
    newCompany.companyName = companyName;
    newCompany.companyAddress = companyAddress;
    newCompany.companyRegNumber = companyRegNumber;
    newCompany.companyContactNumber = companyContactNumber;
    newCompany.companyLogo = companyLogo;

    await newCompany.save();
    res.json({
      successMsg: `${req.body.companyName} Company Added Successfully`
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("clientsController error - Add Company ", err);
    res.status(500).json({
      errorMsg: "Server Error. Please Try again",
    });
  }
};
```

The error i get in the console is this

*clientsController error - Add Company  Error: Company validation failed: companyLogo: Path `companyLogo` is required.*
at ValidationError.inspect

> (C:\CCP\sd08_2021\Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:47:26)

Can you please help me out ?

Comment: You need to upload the image first to your server, then send it from your server to the cloudinary server. Use the `multer` package to upload the file to your server, then use the `cloudinary` package to send it to the cloudinary service. Both of those packages are available from NPM.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it without sending it to the server ?

Comment: No. You can't upload images to cloudinary without registering a cloudinary account and obtaining API keys for that account. You do not want to use those API keys in the browser because your website users can then steal your API keys, and do anything they want to your cloudinary account (like deleting any image, or uploading obscene images). For this reason, you need to do everything server side. Your users will send an image to your server, then your sever will send it to cloudinary, then cloudinary will send back a response with a url to the image, then you can update your database..

Comment: What @TJBlackman says correct about exposing API secret on client-side.
However, you can upload to Cloudinary without exposing your API secret by using either unsigned upload or signed upload. The later is preferred since it's more secure way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your error is caused by a more trivial problem :

When you send the POST request with fetch, you don't actually wait for its completion (it's a promise), so the code in the `if ... else {...}` statement is executed *before the termination of the fetch()* !

`setCompanyLogoURL(data.url)` has not been called yet, so `formData.append('companyLogo', companyLogoURL);` set a blank string instead of the value returned by the call to the Cloudinary API.

The solution would be to make `handleCompanySubmit` *async*, and to await for the `fetch()` promise completion.